# SQL SELECT Multiple Columns Into Merge into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I do NOT want to concatenate anything. Instead, given a table which has **multiple columns**, I want a `SELECT` statement which will then return each of those columns as if they existed in different rows (**ONE COLUMN**). Example...

```
TABLE                         
+--------+---------+---------+                             +--------+
|Person1 | Person2 | Person3 |                             |Person  |
+========+=========+=========+   SELECT *ANSWER HERE*      +========+
|Alex    | Ben     | Charlie |   FROM PEOPLE               |Alex    |
+--------+---------+---------+   ORDER BY *person*?        +--------+
|Dale    | Eric    | Gary    |                             |Ben     |
+--------+---------+---------+   RETURNS ------------>     +--------+
                                                           |Charlie |
 ^^^ NOTE ABOVE HOW WE ^^^                                 +--------+
    HAVE THREE COLUMNS                                     |Dale    |
                                                           +--------+
                                                           |Eric    |
                       NOTE HOW WE ONLY                    +--------+
                       RETURN ONE COLUMN -------------->   |Gary    |
                                                           +--------+
```

Notice: we start with a table that has **three columns** and are now returning a result as if each row were independent.

Comment: If a value is present multiple times (say, "Bob" appears in row 1 and row 2, and/or in column 1 and column 2), should it appear multiple times in the final set?

Comment: No, but I was assuming I could do a group by or something of the sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT but UNION will also work..  Change to UNION ALL to include duplicates..

```
SELECT  Person1 [Person]
FROM    People
UNION
SELECT  Person2
FROM    People
UNION
SELECT  Person3
FROM    People
```

if you'd like to try UNPIVOT to compare performance it would look like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Person
FROM    People 
UNPIVOT ( 
    Person 
    FOR Persons IN ([Person1],[Person2],[Person3]) 
) up
```

using a Table Value Constructor

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Person
FROM    People
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Person1),(Person2),(Person3)) t(Person)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any easy way to shorten the above query?

Comment: @StephenLasky i guess you could use a table value constructor to shorten it some